# I am trying to find the set these Legos belong to

Tags: set-identification

I am trying to find the set these polybags with LEGO bricks belong to.
Can you help me with identifying which set they belong to?

[image][image]

Comment: can you confirm that my answer is correct? Could you find further bags of the set in your collection?

Answer (score 2):

**Bag 1:**

It is the **Amusement Park Roller Coaster (Item No: 41130)**

The [Yellow Dish 6 x 6 Inverted (Radar)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=44375b&colorID=3&in=A) is very seldom, so I searched for sets including this dish and found [41130 Amusement Park Roller Coaster](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41130-1#T=I).

Below the yellow dish you see a seldom
[Minifigure, Utensil Dish 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6256&idColor=104#T=C&C=104) (Item No: 6256) in the picture.

**Bag 2:**
This bag is part of the **Death Star - UCS
(Item No: 10188-1)**

I used the following items in the picture for identification:

- Dark Bluish Gray Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Axle Hole (32064)
- Black Technic, Gear 12 Tooth Double Bevel (32270)
- Dark Bluish Gray Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular Double Split (41678)

Comment: This is valid for top polybag - the bottom one seems to be from another set.

Comment: @Alex good catch. We should split the question then into two set identifications

Comment: Not really, we have had multiple questions like that. You can edit your answer to provide details on next set. Someone else could also identify the 2nd set and provide details as another answer.